# What are the typical values for the three inputs to the Driver circuit board of Infrasolid's thermal emitters in Hispower series?

Tags: infrared, emitter

The technical note provided by Infrasolid provides some details. https://www.infrasolid.com/data/doc/Products/HISpower/HISpower-series-technical-note-operating-mode.pdf?c=20211109191000

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.